# What is the right way to apply font-face in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

At the moment, I am doing it like the following example, is that correct? is there a better way of doing it?

```
/*Font Face*/
@font-face { font-family: Comfortaa; src: url('Comfortaa.ttf') }
@font-face { font-family: Comfortaa; font-weight: bold; src: url('ComfortaaBOLD.ttf') }

/*Fonts*/h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, pre, a, ol, li, span, label, blockquote, figcaption, abbr, td, input, textarea {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 150%;
    color: #4A4A4A;
}
```

---

2) Which of the following methods to apply the BOLD font is correct:

A)

```
strong {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

B)

```
strong {
   font-family: Comfortaa; font-weight: bold; src: url('ComfortaaBOLD.ttf')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would do it like this:

```
@font-face { font-family: Comfortaa; font-weight: normal; src: url('Comfortaa.ttf') }
@font-face { font-family: ComfortaaBold; font-weight: normal; src: url('ComfortaaBOLD.ttf') }

/*Fonts*/h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, pre, a, ol, li, span, label, blockquote, figcaption, abbr, td, input, textarea {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 150%;
    color: #4A4A4A;
}

strong {
   font-family: 'ComfortaaBold';
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

Since you are already importing a bold font you don't have to set the font weight to bold again. Instead, set it to normal to have it render nicely on the screen.